# Anyone knows how to insert/use special characters or symbols in Xib files

Tags: iphone, ipad

Hello Friends i want to use copyright Symbol and Trademark symbol in Xib files

Anyone knows how to insert/use special characters or symbols in Xib files

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Click Edit (top bar) -> Special Characters

**EDIT**

Copyright and TM sign are in the "Letterlike Symbols".

**Xcode 6.2**

Click Edit (top bar) -> "Emoji and Symbols"

Comment: There's also a search field at the bottom of the dialog, just typing "copy" turned up the copyright sign as the first hit, same for "trade".

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer keyboard shortcuts, you can also use Control-Command-Space (^⌘Space) to bringup the Character Viewer.

Note that this also works in the Xcode editor, and not only to add special characters to XIB files